# How to use backreferences as index to substitute via list?

Tags: python, regex-group

I have a list

```py
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

I like to replace all these elements by their index in the list. I know, that I can go through the list and use replace of a string like

```py
text = "I like to eat apple, but banana are fine too."
for i, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    text = text.replace(fruit, str(i))
```

How about using regular expression? With `\number` we can backreference to a match. But

```py
import re

text = "I like to eat apple, but banana are fine too."
text = re.sub('apple|banana|cherry', fruits.index('\1'), text)
```

doesn't work. I get an error that `\x01` is not in fruits. But `\1` should refer to `'apple'`.

I am interested in the most efficient way to do the replacement, but I also like to understand regex better. How can I get the match string from the backreference in regex.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: one efficient way would be to create a dictionary mapping like `{v:str(k) for k,v in enumerate(fruits)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

text = "I like to eat apple, but banana are fine too."
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']

pattern = re.compile("|".join(fruits))
text = pattern.sub(lambda x: str(fruits.index(x.group())), text)
print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
I like to eat 0, but 1 are fine too.
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks very nice. Can you please elaborate how `sub` uses the function argument? And how do I have to modify this example if the pattern yields 5 matches, where the fruit is always the third match?

Comment: The lambda function returns the captured group in the string.

Comment: So, the function gets the matches group as the input and its return is how the match will be replaced? Ok. thanks a lot :-)